# How to take incremental backup in Linux?

Tags: linux, administrator

I'm trying to take backup for my data for rhel, but I not able to take all backup.  Could anybody help show me how I take incremental and full backups? What is the process?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple programs you can use. I'll list only few of those:

- [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/): incremental backups with encryption. Robust command set. [Examples of usage.](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/docs.html)
- [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/): takes reverse diffs. Means that newest version is always complete without adding any incrementals. That way broken incremental is not destroying any files. [Usage examples](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html)
- tar: very simple way to take incremental backups, see for example [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/Incremental-Dumps.html).

---

As I think rdiff-backup is excellent for simple backups, I'll cover it better here.

Assuming you have usb disk mounted to `/mnt/backupdisk`. You can take new backup using

```
sudo rdiff-backup /home /mnt/backupdisk
```

Files in `/mnt/backupdisk` are newest version. Older versions are saved in `rdiff-backup-data` subfolder. Restoring newest file can be done just by copying whatever you need, for example

```
cp /mnt/backupdisk/home/username/.profile /home/username/.profile
```

If you want to (automatically or manually) delete old backups (you don't want to keep those forever, unless you have infinite disk space), you can use

```
rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 2W /mnt/backupdisk
```

to remove backups older than two weeks (change as it's appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

A very comfortable and easy to maintain solution is [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) which uses tar or rsync, pooling techniques and automatic incremental backups. You control it through a web gui.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use rsnapshot, which uses hardlinks to create full backups, while only using the disk space of incremental backups.

This way, I have 7 backups of my server, but in total it only costs me 100% of disk space for the first backup and <5% for the next 6. But i'm always assured of having a full backup around.